# JSON File Not Loading Correctly?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For Some Reason, When I Load a Dictionary With Import Json, It Doesn't Work. It can Print The Dictionary but When I Search for a Existing Key It Acts Like There Isn't One.

```
with open('exp.json') as w:
  exp = json.load(w)

print(exp)

with open('levels.json') as q:
  levels = json.load(q)

@bot.command(aliases = ['rank'])
async def level(ctx):
  if ctx.author.id in exp:
    await ctx.send(f"You Are Level {levels[ctx.author.id]}")
```

Is There Something I Did Wrong?

Comment: Note: It Prints My ID When It Prints the Dict: EXP But On the If ctx.author.id in exp it says its not there

Comment: JSON keys are strings, not integers

Comment: what do you mean by that? sorry im quite new to import json

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have user id as primary keys in (exp.json) file.

Then you should try this program

```
with open('exp.json') as w:
    exp = json.load(w)

print(exp)

with open('levels.json') as q:
    levels = json.load(q)

@bot.command(aliases = ['rank'])
async def level(ctx):
    if str(ctx.message.author.id) in exp.keys():
        await ctx.send(f"You Are Level {levels[str(ctx.message.author.id)]}")
```

Comment: sorry for getting back to you so late, 
thank you! this worked!